# scanner doesn't close using scan.NextInt() and .hasNext() loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read the Input below but the Scanner doesn't close in Java. From the output, I can see all the inputs are taken inside the string, but the console still shows the program is still running. The red square button is still active. Can you please help?

```
4
0 3
2 5
4 2
4 0

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";
        scan.useDelimiter("\\s*");
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(scan.nextInt());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are new to Java and software development. First, you should check the JavaDoc of the `hasNext()` method:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()

Citation: "This method may block while waiting for input to scan."

So you have a continuous loop. If you want to exit your loop, you have to do that explicitly.

Comment: As user @WJS stated, you do not want to close a `Scanner` that was opened on `System.in` as you will find yourself unable to open another `Scanner` on `System.in` again (you are closing `System.in` at the same time).

Comment: @Nexevis you are absolutely correct! Haven't done anything with the scanner for decades and forgot it. I fixed my answer so nobody will pick it up by accident.

Answer (score 2):

The scanner doesn't know when you are going to stop entering data at the console (unlike reading from a file which signals  an EOF). So it blocks, waiting for more input. So you have several options.

- You can either type Ctrl-D (or what ever your OS requires to signal an EOF).
- You can use special input to stop checking (Like a "Done" string) (which means you will need to parse ints if you want integer input too.)
- Or you can initially prompt for an integer to indicate how much data to type in via a loop.

You can also do the following:

```
while (true) {
    if (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        // requires a non-empty and non-numeric value.
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
}
```

But `do not close the Scanner` after reading from the console.  Otherwise you will not be able to reopen it and take input within the same program.

Comment: Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int exit;
        String input = "";
        scan.useDelimiter("\\s");
        exit = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < exit; i++) {
            input += scan.nextLine();
        }
My string is now 0 32 54 24 0 but I used delimiter \s So then I used replaceAll() to take out the space like so System.out.print(input.replaceAll(" ", "")); Did I write the delimiter wrong or use the wrong scanner method? Thanks.